# ddrescue correct tool for an HD, if testdisk finds no partition? Other tools?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery, read-only

I'm on Linux and have an HD (ext4, not ssd), that suddenly was remounted as read-only. After a restart, said HD was shown as having no partition. testdisk didn't find the partition (should be only one, spanning the whole HD). I soon will have a replacement drive and I'm wondering if ddrescue is the right tool to try to rescue the data in such a case. Or should I look for some other tool?

Edit: The suggested link references decades old apps that I'm not feeling content with using (let alone getting them to work at all).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 21.10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover data from a failing hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19297/how-to-recover-data-from-a-failing-hard-drive)

Comment: @karel, I'm not sure, as it doesn't describe my case with a missing partition (as far as I can see). But I will give that "Unstoppable Copier" a try, thank you.

Comment: I selected the question with Spinrite in its answers especially for your case.

Comment: @karel
That program is pretty old and relies on older system libraries that aren't available anymore in the standard repositories, so I wouldn't feel comfortable using that.
So, no, that link unfortunately doesn't answer my question. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You're the expert here, huh? [Creating a bootable USB stick to run Spinrite](https://forums.grc.com/threads/creating-bootable-usb-stick-to-run-spinrite.521/).

Comment: I'll look at spinrite, but the comment made on that other conversation doesn't sound promising. Anyhow, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recover data from a clicking/dying external drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158855/how-can-i-recover-data-from-a-clicking-dying-external-drive)